# Dictionary compile error: method or data member not found

Tags: excel, vba

Not sure why getting the above error. I have a class module named `clsRemit` with code:

```
Sub clsRemit()

Public vendor As String
Public amount As Long
Public invoices As String

End Sub
```

Then in my module, I have:

```
For Each v In dictlist.Keys
    If InStr(1, .Cells(q, "B").Value2, v, vbTextCompare) Then
        vendor = .Cells(q, "B").Value2

        If dict.Exists(vendor) = True Then
            Set oVend = dict(vendor)
        Else
            Set oVend = New clsRemit
            dict.Add vendor, oVend
        End If

        oVend.vendor = vendor 'error here
        oVend.invoices = oVend.invoices & vbCrLf & .Cells(q, "F")
        oVend.amount = oVend.amount + .Cells(q, "G").Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: That `clsRemit` code is wrong, `Public` can't compile in a procedure scope. Is that `Sub clsRemit` really there or the class has 3 public fields?

Comment: The code in clsRemit shouldn't be wrapped in a Sub. The variables should be Dimmed as private then accessed through Public Properties. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx

Comment: @Tragamor public fields are exposed as public get+let properties in the clsRemit default interface anyway - if the class is just a DTO, explicit properties are likely overkill/redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> oVend.vendor = vendor 'error here
> ```

That's a red herring. The real problem is here:

> ```
> Sub clsRemit()
>
> Public vendor As String
> Public amount As Long
> Public invoices As String
>
> End Sub
> ```

`Public` (or `Private`, for that matter) is illegal in a procedure scope. Remove the procedure scope, the code should compile:

```
Option Explicit
Public vendor As String
Public amount As Long
Public invoices As String
```

Comment: Huh. I had no idea a class module could just be declarations!

Comment: Heh. That's all Latin to me as I am not a programmer but thumbs up for linking to Matt's project rubberduck ^_^

Comment: @findwindow I *am* the Matt in question lol - you'll like the "I'm not a programmer" recent post on that blog ;-)

Comment: Oh wait. Thought your handle was `Matt'sMug`?? Edit: sorry if I am mixing you up with another person.

Comment: It was, until March of last year =)

Comment: Ahh ok. So it IS you! Long time no see ^___^

Comment: So that post on classes...I can't read it lol. Still Latin to me. I feel like you should write a compiler. Anticipate/identify bugs and fix them during compile ~_^ Great post on "not a programmer". Totally agree with sentiment but there isn't enough time to do my actual job _and_ write code with those expectations XD

Comment: I will have to check it out when it gets there!